# OpenCV order of RotatedRect vertices

Tags: opencv

When we retrieve the vertices of a RotatedRect in OpenCV with `rect.points(pts)`, what is the order of the vertices being picked. In other words, which vertex is the first element in output vector `pts`? Is there any general principle or just random?

Answer (score -1):

While passing the points to a RotatedRect, the points can be in any arbitrary order. For a given set of points the Output would always be consistent for any random arrangement of fixed set of points.